# Angular Material mat-select: cancel selection change event

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to figure out how to cancel mat-select (Angular Material 7.3.7) change event and restore to previous state in event handler. Is it possible?

My select control:

```
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-select #visualOptionsSelect formControlName="competenceVisualOption" (selectionChange)="visualOptionSelectionChanged($event)"
                                required>
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let visualOption of availableVisualOptions" [value]="visualOption">
                            {{visualOption.name}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
```

When some conditions are met I want to cancel selection and leave previous selected item. Using reactive forms I tried to store currently selected item in separate variable and make comparison in `valueChanges` subscription of `competenceVisualOption` control. But this looks quite messy. Also I have other dependencies on this selected item, therefore I'll need to process them manually too.

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, seems that there is no out-of-the-box feature that I can use. The only way of solving my problem is to store 'last' selected value - I can rollback to it if needed.

My template code:

```
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-select #visualOptionsSelect placeholder="Тип отображения" formControlName="templateCompetenceVisualOption" (selectionChange)="visualOptionSelectionChanged($event.value)"
                                required>
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let visualOption of availableVisualOptions" [value]="visualOption">
                            {{visualOption.name}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
```

In selectionchange event handler - `selectionChange` - I always store current selected value and then revert to it after new selection if user answers 'No' to question (I use `sweetalert2` library for popups)

```
visualOptionSelectionChanged(selectedVisualOption: CompetenceVisualOption) {

    //если ранее поле было не заполнено, то не задаем вопрос
    if (!this.lastActiveVisualOption) {

        //перезапишем предыдущее активное значение
        this.lastActiveVisualOption = selectedVisualOption;
        return;
    }

    swal({
        text: 'При смене отображения вариантов ответов, предыдущие значения сбросятся. Сменить отображение ответов?',
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Да',
        cancelButtonText: 'Нет',
        confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-primary",
        cancelButtonClass: "btn btn-secondary cfb-btn-border",
        buttonsStyling: false
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {

            // перерисуем область ответов
            this._setRatingLevelOptionsComponent(selectedVisualOption.code);
            //перезапишем предыдущее активное значение
            this.lastActiveVisualOption = selectedVisualOption;
        }
        else {
            //если выбрали Нет, то вернем прежний вариант и варианты ответа не трогаем
            this.templateCompetenceVisualOption.setValue(this.lastActiveVisualOption);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: your answer is really helpful the only point of confusion is #visualOptionsSelect  can you please tell the purpose of using #visualOptionsSelect?

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version:

```html
<mat-select #aValueEl [value]="aValue" (selectionChange)="changeAValue($event, aValueEl)">...</mat-select>
```

```
class AComponent {
  ...
  aValue: string = "initial-value";
  changeAValue(event: MatSelectChange, component: MatSelect) {
    if (event.value === "invalid-value") {
      alert("You can't choose this value");
      component.value = this.aValue;
      return;
    }
    this.aValue = event.value;
    return;
  }

}
```